# How can I get BIG-IP Edge vpn for Ubuntu 18.10? Or can I use any alterantive?

Tags: vpn, 18.10

How can I get/install BIG-IP Edge vpn for Ubuntu 18.10? Or can I use any alterantive?

Comment: https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_apm/manuals/product/apm-client-configuration-12-0-0/5.html

Comment: I tried, do you have any idea about do it through the firefox borwser?

Comment: The link actually answers your question. It has a Linux client so it can be used in Ubuntu. For support questions about the service you should contact the service provider.

Comment: The link does not provide a Linux client, at least not one that can be dowloaded. Do you have a link with the actual linux client?

Answer (score 2):

You can download it only after proper registrations (it's free).

Go to http://downloads.f5.com, it will redirect you to login page. There you have a *register* link. Just register, follow instructions on mail, and then you just have to login to be able to download software.

For BIG-IP client there is a big .iso (APM Clients, +200MB) with all the BIG-IP clients for all platforms. Download it, extract it, find yours and you are ready to go.

Comment: Managed to create an account, I'm forced to set a password, but that fails unfortunately.

Comment: Managed to set a password, but unable to download. Can you upload the pack somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/cmorty/f5vpn-login . Depending on how old this answer is, you might want to check if someone has a newer version: https://github.com/cmorty/f5vpn-login/network

https://github.com/kayrus/gof5 seems to be maintained, too. There might be others, too.